# Changing the scale interval of a Continuous Histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to plot a continuous histogram from the following code but my intervals on both axes are not as desired. I want to have a 500 interval on x-axis from 0 to 3000 and 200 interval on y-axis from 0 to 1000. How can i have that?

```
library(lubridate)
library("ggplot2")
str(lakers$date)
lakers$date <- ymd(lakers$date) 
str(lakers$date) 
lakers$time<-ms(lakers$time)
lakers$time <- as.duration(lakers$time)
lakers$time <-as.numeric(dminutes(c(12, 24, 36, 48, 53)[lakers$period]) -lakers$time)
qplot(time, data=lakers, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 60,main="Figure 3: The graph on the left displays seconds on the x axis.")
```

**Current Output**
[image: current output]]

**Desired Output**
[image: Desired Output]]

Comment: set limits and breaks using `scale_x_continuous` http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html

Comment: @waterling does this function has to be included within qplot? and i tried looking at documentation but it does not provides information about scaling time values and my x axis is in time. could you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: See `scale_x_time` then. But you made `lakers$time` numeric, so that won't work.

Comment: Don't use `qplot`, build a proper ggplot object using `ggplot(xy, aes(...)...) + geom_histogram()`. Changing anything can be done by including just another line.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik i've tried with ggplot but the main issue is of the scale interval which still persists. can we change it in ggplot as i could not find the solution for it as in from 0-1000 to 0-500.

Comment: @Axeman any other workaround for changing the intervals?

Comment: Of course, adapting the scale is a fairly common practice, which is why others have suggested using `scale_x_continuous`.

Comment: Did you read waterling's link? Why is `scale_x_continious` not working?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik thanks that really helped..could this difference in the peaks and shape be due to the versioning of lubridate package and the lakers data attached with it?

Comment: @Rehan if I had to guess, I would say play with bin size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it using `ggplot()` instead of `qplot()`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
lakers$date <- ymd(lakers$date) 
lakers$time<-ms(lakers$time)
lakers$time <- as.duration(lakers$time)
lakers$time <-as.numeric(dminutes(c(12, 24, 36, 48, 53)[lakers$period]) -lakers$time)

ggplot(lakers, aes(x = time)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 3000, by = 500)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1400, by = 200))
```

[image]